# can't see response different from "text" as output from a watson assistant node in node-red

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, node-red, watson-conversation

first of all let me tell you that I'm asking my first question here, so please forgive me if I do something wrong.

[image: node response different from text, working on watson tryout environement]

[image: my node-red flow using watson assistant]

I have a couple nodes using response types different from "text", i.e. using images and options, as shown in first picture I linked. When my flow (see pic 2) in node-red activates such a node response from the chatbot assistant, I do not have any output from the node.

Here is the json for one of the nodes I can't get coming through.

```
{"type":"standard",
 "title":"analisi sintomi computer",
 "output":{"generic":[{
           "title":"Quale modello di PC stai utilizzando?",
 "source":"http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/~/media/images/staticpages/thinkpad_ss.ashx?la=en",
"description":"puoi trovare il codice qui",
"response_type":"image"},
{"title":"Quale modello di PC stai utilizzando?","options":[{"label":"T470","value":{"input":{"text":"T470"}}},
{"label":"T450","value":{"input":{"text":"T450"}}},
{"label":"T230","value":{"input":{"text":"T230"}}}],"description":"(vedi qui sopra come individuare il codice esatto)","response_type":"option"},
{"values":[],"response_type":"text","selection_policy":"sequential"}]},"parent":"node_1_1536313247338","metadata":{},
"conditions":"$tipoDevice:computer","dialog_node":"node_2_1536588442374"}
```

Is it an issue with the node in node-red or am I missing something?
thanks for your help

Comment: Your images are impossible to read. I would recommend to reduce the problem to a simple example, and make the code available for that sample.

Comment: Are you using the correct version of the Watson Assistant API, is it configured? The new response types are only available on a recent API version.

Comment: @Simon O'Doherty: thanks for your suggestion, I'll edit to include actual code.

Comment: @data_henrik: I'm using node-red locally with last available version of ibm-watson nodes from node.js; the watson assistant node is configured correctly as far as I can go and I do get all text response, I do not see any output for response types "option" and "image".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it seems like the Node for Watson Assistant / Watson Conversation is not using the required API version to return the multimedia responses:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-node-watson/blob/master/services/conversation/v1.js

That file has the version "2018-02-16" encoded. However, [you need API version "2018-07-10" for that, see the Release Notes](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/release-notes.html#release-notes).

You can set the API version as `msg.params.version`.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was it and I fixed :) now I just have to manage the output somwhow.